# Is there a way to create a Windows perfmon data collector based on process name?

Tags: windows, windows-7, perfmon

### Always Log CPU Usage for an Application "Name"

During some phase of testing, I'd like to *always* monitor the CPU usage of my application. The application has a fixed name.

I don't see a way in the GUI tools to accomplish this, since the Process class always wants a PID.

Is there a way to create a data collector for any process with that name?
It would be very convenient if I could leave it running all the time so that successive invocations of my app always get collected, including after restarting the OS.

**Clarification**: I want to create the collector *before* the process ever runs, and I don't want to have to update it every time the process starts (which would be a requirement if I used the PID).

I'm sure I could modify my app to create its own temporary data collector every time it starts. I like that idea *much* less than something external to the application doing the job. I could probably also create a service (or other style of long-running process) that looks for my app to start, then creates a data collector.

The real question is: **Does Windows have tools do to this job already?**

The best answer I'd like to see uses typical windows features and doesn't involve services or scripts I'd need to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid I don't understand your question. Are you using one of the data collector templates or the manual setup? With manual setup, I see lots of process names under the process class.[image: perfData]

Update

You can create the DCS with this command

```
logman.exe create counter Bingo -c "\Process(explorer)\% Processor Time"
```

Replace "explorer" with the name of your app.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788038(v=ws.11).aspx

Then you configure the start trigger for that DCS within task scheduler to start at bootup.

```
Task Scheduler/Microsoft/Windows/PLA/Bingo
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeff_stokes/2011/11/16/how-to-sustain-your-data-collector-set-through-a-reboot/
[image]

Comment: See my clarification. I want the collector to be defined _before_ the process has started.